# Add a factory type to factories.yml in symfony-1.4

Tags: architecture, configuration, symfony1, symfony-1.4

[factories.yml](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories) is the limited symfony1 version of the full-fledged service container in s2. I would like to implement additional factories beyond the built-in ones, but I don't see anything like that in the docs. Anyone done this?

Comment: looks like the key classes are sfContext and sfFactoryConfigHandler, the latter of which needs to be extended and modified, and is not written in a flexible way :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately symfony 1 has a hardcoded list of factories generated objects available and you will not be able to alter this without patching the framework itself (which is not unreasonable, since 1.x branch won't have new features anymore, conflicting upgrades are not likely)

the code you will need to patch will be probably somewhere around this: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/config/sfFactoryConfigHandler.class.php#L34

just few good patching-the-framework advices:

- backup your 'patch base' files
- make your patch, **test it**
- generate diff between original version and patched version (i.e. using linux `diff` command)

**store diff with description in you sources repository**

This way if you ever need to upgrade your framework's minor versions, just update code and reapply patch (linux - `patch -p0 < mydifffile` - google for details) - hopefully there won't be any conflicts and everything will work just fine.